# Paint that works on galvanized steel and exhaust pipe

Tags: paint, boat, metal, material, steel

I have a homemade outboard motor extension handle similar to this: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07BWXZN2J/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

[image]

The narrow part on the right is  hand-sanded galvanized steel pipe (chainlink fence pipe).  The wider part on the left is bare exhaust pipe. The two pieces are welded together.

I want to paint the entire thing to prevent corrosion and to make it look good.

What kind of paint should I use? I'm under the impression most paints and primers are designed for galvanized steel, or regular steel, but not both.

*I'm aware that welding galvanized steel produces toxic fumes and should avoided or prepped/ground away. I didn't do the welding myself.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My "suggestion" is to put a rust encapsulator like [POR-15](https://www.por15.com) (no affiliation) or a similar product, then go back over it with a couple of coats of spray on enamel. The POR-15 will keep it from rusting as well as will be a good base for the paint to stick to, then the paint will make it look good. POR-15 will deteriorate under direct sunlight, so it needs the extra coatings of the spray on enamel to keep it good.

As an aside, if you do go this route, be careful with the POR-15 as it sticks to everything. Once you open the can, pretty much use it then throw the rest away, because when the stuff gets into the crease of the can lid, it will bond the lid to it. Also use throw away paint brushes, because there's no way to clean this stuff out of them. Clothing, eye-protection, and nitrile gloves help as well.

Comment: @user1974 If you decide to use 2 coats of POR-15, pay particularly close attention to the label directions. The first coat must still be slightly tacky when you apply the second coat. If you wait until it is fully dry and hard, the second coat will not spread, but will bead up like water on a waxed car body. If using a brush, you can prevent it from hardening between the first and second coats by wrapping the brush tightly in kitchen plastic wrap.

Comment: In addition to above suggestions, coat the inside of tube as moisture or salt water will seep in and corrode from the inside, ruining any treatment done on the exterior. Once galvanized plating is sanded off, the steel tube is exposed to moisture and/or salt water environment.

Comment: Agree with both comments above.